# When serving a response cached by the server, IIS 7 is stripping the Vary header

Tags: caching, iis, iis-7, http-headers

I’m using a custom framework for bundling stylesheets and scripts. (I.e., these are dynamically generated responses, not static files.)

The response for the initial request, when the response is being generated for the very first time, includes these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, no-transform, max-age=31536000
Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 18:15:50 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 16:19:36 GMT
Content-Length: 3126
```

Now that the response above has been generated and cached by the server, subsequent requests for the same stylesheet are responded to with these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, no-transform, max-age=31536000
Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 18:15:50 GMT
Date: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 16:20:00 GMT
Content-Length: 3126
```

Ignoring the new `Date` value, the headers are identical with the obvious exception of the missing `Vary` header.

One nasty consequence that I’ve seen in the wild is that if the very first response generated for a given asset is not compressed (due to the corresponding client not supporting compression), then the server caches that non-compressed response and serves it for all subsequent requests to all clients.

**Any idea how to have the server retain the `Vary` header for cached responses?**

I’m using `HttpCacheability.Public` for these responses. I can avoid the issue by using `HttpCacheability.Private` instead, but I’d prefer to allow the server and proxies to cache responses.

Some reading has led me to believe that IIS can’t do “kernel caching” if you vary by encoding. But I’m not sure if that means I can’t cache on the server *at all* or if it just prevents a special kind of server-side caching.

### Update:

I was originally using the following to set the `Vary` header:

```
response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
```

I tried a different method of specifying it:

```
response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("Accept-Encoding");
```

That caused `Vary` to never be emitted. Not even on the very first response.

As a last resort, I’m also considering using:

```
response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
```

That causes the `Cache-Control` header to still specify `public` (so that proxies can still cache), but prevents the server from caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with the update I made to the question, I tried yet another way of specifying the `Vary` header:

```
response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
```

…And it fixed the problem. Responses now retain the `Vary` header across requests from multiple clients and are also cached by the server.